# How to notify React components about status change

Tags: reactjs

Is it easier than pass argument from parent to child and turn on binding to know state of a component changed?

https://dev.to/zeyadetman/how-to-pass-state-between-components-in-reactjs-2pg1

Comment: It would either be that or use a state management library (like Redux) which kinda is the same as passing data as props, but stored in a single place. 

Notifying components via eventlisteners is possible also but in my opinion, it isn't worth it.

Comment: Hi @Edrian, what if components are siblings?